# StreamBuilder inside FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, stream-builder

I am trying to understand how `async`/`await`, `FutureBuilder`s and `StreamBuilder`s work. I have to get an item from database, for that I'm using `FutureBuilder` and then show it on UI. But user can also change this loaded data to I am using `StreamBuilder` to handle all changes and update UI accordingly. Here is the view code:

```
body: FutureBuilder<bool>(
  future: getFutureObj(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator()
      );
    }

    return StreamBuilder<ModelClass>(
      stream: streamObj,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<ModelClass> snapshot) {

        if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.imagePath == null || snapshot.data.imagePath.isEmpty) {
          return Container(
            height: 200,
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }

        return Image(
          image: Image.file(File(snapshot.data.imagePath)).image,
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 200,
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
        );
      }
    );
  }
)
```

Now the problem I am facing is that when `Future` is completed, and I add data in `Stream`, the builder callback of `StreamBuilder` is never called with data in it. But if I add a little delay in it, then it starts working. Here is the BLoC code:

```
Future<bool> getFutureObj() {
  final Completer<bool> completer = Completer();
  Future.microtask(() {
    _data = ModelClass();
  })
  .then((value) {
    completer.complete(true);
    stream.add(_data);
  });
  return completer.future;
}
```

But if I replace

```
stream.add(_data);
```

with

```
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 300), () => stream.add(_data));
```

then it starts to work. Why is that? Why adding a delay fixed the issue? And how can I fix it without relying on delays. Thank you.

Comment: Where does that `_data` come from?

Comment: It is global in my bloc class

Comment: I suspect that you use that `completer.complete(true)` to set `_data` somewhere else. That will be async, thus, your `stream.add(_data)` will be `null` in that call that will end synchronously and in the next event loop (when you add that `Future.delayed()`) will actually have data.

Comment: The `completer.complete(true)` is only used to call builder function of `FutureBuilder`. It is not being used anywhere else and it is working fine.

Comment: But we don't have to think in these terms only. I just want to get rid of the delay. Is it possible in any way?

Comment: I need to understand where that `_data` is set so I can help you get rid of it. The delay is working because your `_data` will still be `null` at that point, but not after the delay.

Comment: `_data` is set inside the `loadData()` function, which is called before `completer.complete(true);`

Comment: @MiguelRuivo can you please guide me in right direction regarding this problem? Or do you need more code to understand the issue?